# Error: ngModel:datefmt

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php. everything works great except the "date" option. when "input type= "text" => everything works ok just need to set the date as "2016-16-8". but I want to change it to type "date" to pick a date but I don't know why that doesn't work. can anyone please help?

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="order_date"> תאריך:</label>
            <input type="date" id="order_date" name="order_date" class="form-control" placeholder="*שדה חובה*" ng-model="order.order_date" />

        </div>
```

PHP:

```
$sql_statement = "Insert into orders (order_type, date,total_payment , status, technical_data, refer_customer_id) values ('"
  .$data->data->order_type ."','" .$data->data->order_date ."'," .$data->data->total_payment .",'"
  .$data->data->status ."','" .$data->data->technical_data ."'," .$data->data->refer_customer_id .")" ;
```

Comment: 1. Use prepared statement and bind params instead of constructing SQL string by yourself, cause library will escape insufficient data;

2. Which data do you have in your `$data->data->order_date`?

Comment: in my php code? @atn

Comment: Yes, in your PHP code.

Comment: @atn this?   if( $result->num_rows!=0)
    {
        $order->order_id = $row['order_id'];
        $order->order_type = $row['order_type'];
        $order->order_date =$row['date'];

        $order->total_payment = $row['total_payment'];
        $order->technical_data = $row['technical_data'];
        $order->status = $row['status'];
        $order->refer_customer_id = $row['refer_customer_id'];
    }

Comment: Which value you passing to DB? What do you have in `$data->data->order_date`?

I read your other questions. Please use prepared statements to DB access: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php